# Speed up pixel iteration

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pixel, uicolor

The problem I'm having is not being able to iterate over all the pixels in a UIImage quickly enough, checking each colour against a particular one (green). The iteration must be processed as soon as the user initiates it. At the moment there's a ~0.5s delay.

I'm using this to create a screenshot of the view:

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage { 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return screenShot!  
}
```

This to obtain the colour of a single pixel:

```
extension UIImage {

    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

And this loop to check each pixel of the image:

```
testImage = screenshot()
greenPresent = false

for yCo in 0 ..< Int(testImage.size.height) {
    for xCo in 0 ..< Int(testImage.size.width) {

        if testImage.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: xCo, y: yCo)) == UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1) {
            greenPresent = true
            greenCount += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Performance takes a hit on a scale factor of 0.0; I am looking to accommodate this.

Comment: FYI - questions like this may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should I post the same question there?

Comment: No. Either post here or there, not both.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vastly more efficient version of the code you posted:

```
testImage = imageFromView()
var greenCount = 0
if let cfdata = testImage.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data {
    let data = cfdata as Data
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: data.count, by: 4) {
        let r = data[i]
        let g = data[i+1]
        let b = data[i+2]
        if g == 255 && r == 0 && b == 0 {
            greenCount += 1
        }
    }
}
```

This code eliminates many inefficiencies in the original code. The data is only obtained once. No points are used. The data bytes are accessed directly. No `UIColor` creation is needed. No conversion to `CGFloat` is needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much faster was this code compared your original code?

Comment: It's almost instant, unlike how it was. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Tim I see you unaccepted the answer. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: Scale will be 1.0 only on very old iOS devices such as iPad 2 or an iPhone 3G. Those old devices are very slow. Do you really need to support such old versions of iOS used by those old devices?

Comment: My mistake - I meant to say 0.0 (UIScreen.main.scale).

Comment: That actually makes more sense. When you use 0, it uses the device's screen scale. Your old code generated 1x images. Now, using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, your are generating 2x and 3x images. That's 4x and 9x the number of pixels so it will take 4 or 9 times longer to process.

Comment: It's still VERY slow on 2k x 2k image, hundreds to thousands of ms. The only really fast way is to write a pixel shader.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *caching* the `data` pointer:

```
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = ...
```

as opposed to computing it from scratch *every* single time you call the `getPixelColor` method.

Also: consider creating a simple `struct Color` instead of using the standard `class UIColor`. Creating (and deallocating) that many `class` instances might get expensive quickly!

---

By the way, you should also add a simple `break` after finding the desired pixel. Of course, assuming your final algorithm stays the same ;-)

Comment: This is huge. The current code is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Paulo Mattos, I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, break out of your loop as soon as you find a green pixel:

```
yLoop: for yCo in 0 ..< Int(testImage.size.height) {
    for xCo in 0 ..< Int(testImage.size.width) {
        if testImage.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: xCo, y: yCo)) == UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1) {
            greenPresent = true
            break yLoop
        }
    }
}
```

Since all you want to know is if there's a single green pixel, there's no point in continuing after you find one. This will speed your check up by 50% on average (although a single green pixel at the bottom right will take just as long as ever).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I considered that but I need to iterate over every pixel. Question updated.